# Swipe to go back not working in flutter webview in ios

Tags: flutter, flutterwebviewplugin

Tried flutter webview. Implemented `WillPopScope` to control the back press referring [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57878887/using-flutter-webview-as-home-and-pressing-back-button-closes-application#) example. In android swipe to go back gestures works, but in ios it doesn't work. This does not detect the gesture. How to solve this?

Code:

```
WebViewController controllerGlobal;
Future<bool> _exitApp(BuildContext context) async {
  print('back press');
  if (await controllerGlobal.canGoBack()) {
    print("onwill goback");
    controllerGlobal.goBack();
  } else {
    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(
      const SnackBar(content: Text("No back history item")),
    );
    return Future.value(false);
  }
}


class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  final Completer<WebViewController> _controller =
      Completer<WebViewController>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () => _exitApp(context),
      child: Scaffold(
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return WebView(
                initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
                javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                onWebViewCreated: (WebViewController webViewController) {
                  _controller.complete(webViewController);
                },
                onPageFinished: (String url) {
                  print('Page finished loading: $url');
                },
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Note: Tested in ios simulator only

Comment: `Swipe to go back` can you please add your code snippet for more clear to me?

Comment: I edited the question. Swipe to go back is a gesture in iOS Swipe from left or right edge of the screen which act as a back press

Answer (score 0):

WillPopScope will cause this.
See more detail in https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14203

Comment: Please elaborate and add your answer verbosely instead of posting a link-only answer as some links might become inaccessible in the future.